# VBA function IFERROR THEN GO TO LINE X

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, error-handling, web-scraping

I am having some trouble with ON ERROR GOTO function in VBA. Actually, I am not really sure if what I want is really possible.

I am gathering some information in different websites and the full code is here

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
Dim Ano As Long
Dim offsetCount As Long
Dim URL As String
Dim NUMERO As String

Ano = 2012
offsetCount = 2

Do While Ano >= 2005

    Range("E1").Value = Ano
    Range("D2").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Row <= 5571
        URL = ActiveCell.Text
TryEnterSite:
        IE.navigate URL

        Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set html = IE.document

        On Error GoTo TryEnterSite

        NUMERO = html.getElementById("conteudo_meio").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText

        If IsNumeric(NUMERO) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, offsetCount) = Str(NUMERO)
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, offsetCount) = NUMERO
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

    offsetCount = offsetCount + 1
    Ano = Ano - 1

Loop
```

the problem is that in the line where IE navigates to the URL (IE.navigate URL), sometimes the website just won't enter (internal problem). Because of that the html.getelement does not find the element and gives me "element not found" and the macro stops. The error I get is RUN-TIME ERROR 91: OBJECT VARIABLE OR WITH BLOCK VARIABLE NOT SET.

What I want is: when VBA does not find the object, it should go back to IE.navigate line. Is it possible? How do I do this? I am trying for days to find something but I was unsuccesful.

Comment: `NUMERO = html.getElementById("conteudo_meio").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText`  I dont think this line is actually correct

Comment: @Jeanno As long as the HTML element exists it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IFERROR` is an Excel function. You don't use that to handle VBA runtime errors.

What you need is an `On Error GoTo` statement, and a control flow that goes something like this:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim result As String

TryGetResult:
    result = GetResult(ActiveCell.Text)

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    'MsgBox Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Resume TryGetResult
End Sub
```

Where `GetResult` is a function that encapsulates your IE logic - it's not *needed* per se, but breaking down your code into smaller functions/procedures that do fewer things will make it much easier to maintain (and debug!) your code.

The `Resume <label>` instruction tells the execution flow to return to that specific label (a label is an identifier followed by a colon - `Label:`). `Resume` all by itself would return to the line that raised the error, and `Resume Next` would return to the line immediately following the line that raised the error.

Note that your loop construct seems to set you up for infinite looping, and I'm not sure about that `Sleep 1000` there - you have 5000+ rows to go through, and you're sleeping a whole second between each one.

Also `If IsNumeric(NUMERO) = True Then` should be `If IsNumeric(NUMERO) Then` - there's no need to compare a Boolean value to a Boolean constant to make a Boolean expression for an If statement: a Boolean value *is* a Boolean expression!

You're working with `ActiveCell` - that's somewhat frail: the user could click somewhere while your code is in the `DoEvents` loop, and activate a cell you're not expecting to be activated, and that wouldn't be pretty. Instead, work with `Worksheet` and `Range` objects.

---

Here's how I would go about it - say your method is called `DoSomething` (you didn't include the method's signature). You need to tell VBA where to jump when there's an error, like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim Ano As Long
    Dim offsetCount As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim NUMERO As String

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    Ano = 2012
    offsetCount = 2

    Do While Ano >= 2005

        Range("E1").Value = Ano
        Range("D2").Select

        Do While ActiveCell.Row <= 5571
            URL = ActiveCell.Text
    TryEnterSite:
            IE.navigate URL

            Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
                Sleep 1000 'give it a second
                DoEvents
            Loop

            Set html = IE.document

            NUMERO = html.getElementById("conteudo_meio").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText

            If IsNumeric(NUMERO) Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, offsetCount) = Str(NUMERO)
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, offsetCount) = NUMERO
            End If

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Loop

        offsetCount = offsetCount + 1
        Ano = Ano - 1

    Loop

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Err.Clear
    Resume TryEnterSite
End Sub
```

That's a start. Now when there's **any** error, the code will jump to `TryEnterSite` until it works - if the input (url) is just bad, it will keep looping forever, so you should have a way of validating the url before you *try it until it works* - but that's a different issue.

What I meant above, was that the loop's body would be better off extracted into its own function. Also you shouldn't be working off `ActiveCell` *at all*. Instead of this:

```
Range("D2").Select
```

I would do this:

```
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Set xlSheet = Sheet1 'or ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim xlRow As Long
xlRow = 2

Dim xlRange As Range
For xlRow = 2 To 5571

    Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("D" & xlRow)
    '...

Next
```

And then you have a *range* object that doesn't depend on the current selection - so instead of making a selection and moving that selection around, your loop just increments a row number, and in the loop's body you `Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("D" & xlRow)`, and work with that object instead - and then the user can't break your macro by simply clicking somewhere while your code is in a `Sleep`/`DoEvents` loop.

---

Hope it helps. Sorry if this is a bit over-the-top of an answer, I'm more used to reviewing working code on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - feel free to go there post your code once it works as intended; the community there will help you make it cleaner & better :)

Comment: Hi Mat! Thanks for your answer, but I am not really understading how to implement that in my code. I need it to run, and only when I get an error it would go back to label trygetresult again. I don't know where I would put "exit sub". And thanks for all the other suggestions, Ive changed my code a bit!

Comment: `Exit Sub` goes right before the error-handling subroutine / label, so that the error-handling code only ever runs when there's an error. In my answer I've replaced the body with that `GetResult` function, which encapsulates the IE logic. Good luck!

Comment: Mat, please check my question again, I have edited it and the full code is there now. Tks

Comment: @LuccasEsperKlotz thanks for the checkmark! I've edited with more details.

Comment: It's running here for some time already, I think it works! I will post any news! thank you very much :)